# Why did Prophet Muhammad say that a baby develops in 4 months and not 9?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

In several Sahih Bukhari Hadith, Prophet Muhammad says that a baby develops in 4 months. For example, Sahih al-Bukhari 3208, Sahih al-Bukhari 3332, and Sahih al-Bukhari 6594. Are these Hadith reliable,if yes then are they scientificly accurate?

Comment: Please add hadith quotes not #. The numeration of hadith compilation is not standardized! Secondly if a hadith is in any of both sahihs then it is accepted as authentic by the ummah. Thirdly why the prophet says something: simply because Allah gave him this knowledge. Still we need a full quote of at least one of these ahadith to go deeper in explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In **no** where did The Prophet, ﷺ say that a baby **fully** *biologically develops* in 4 months in these Hadiths. The Prophet ﷺ was talking about the first **four** stages that a fetus goes through during its initial 40-day cycles in its mother's womb. Where the fetus first takes the form of a spermatozoon, then takes the form of a clot of thick blood, then takes the form of a piece of flesh, then afterward, for the rest of the development (fourth stage), he/she begins to form features and Allah fashions (shapes) him/her in the wombs as He wills until birth. Moreover, during the fourth stage, the Hadiths also mention the metaphysical incidents that occur to a baby in the womb.